# SSIS lookup datatype mismatch

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Warning: I have no experience in SSIS, and not much in SQL Server, so this may be a stupid question.

I am tasked with updating a table in a database on a different server, on a regular basis. I have followed the Stairway to Integration Services articles on SQLServer Central, and I think I have designed it correctly, but I have a problem with the lookup to identify which rows should be updated.

The difficulty is that I have 2 fields in my source data (TaxOfficeNumber nvarchar(3) and PAYERef nvarchar(50)) which correlate to a single field EmployerPAYEReference varchar(256) in the destination table. In addition, the destination fields have lost any leading zeroes. So '0123' and 'MYREF' in my table should link to '23/MYREF' in the destination.

I'v managed to cast everything so the same format and datatype, but I can't connect the fields in the Lookup.

My source looks like:

```
SELECT Submitter_Ref_Number
      , Transmission_DateTime
      , MessageStatus
      , HMRC_UniqueID
      , HMRC_Ack_DateTime
      , Product_Name
      , CAST(CAST(CAST(TaxDistrictNumber AS int) AS varchar(3)) + '/' + PAYERef AS varchar(50)) AS EmployerPAYReference 
FROM dbo.P11D
```

and the lookup looks like:

```
SELECT [EmployerPAYEReference]
  FROM [P11D].[dbo].[hmrc_test]
```

In the Lookups editor, when I try to link the columns, I get an error: cnnot match the input column to te lookup column because the data types do not match.

I've tried various options and got nowhere, so any suggestions?

Using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: are you by any chance using NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR or vice versa? SQL is very picky about the datatypes so first check that.

Comment: So I gathered! Types are exactly as I have shown them - originally nvarchar in the source, which I have cast to varchar, and originally varchar in the lookup, not changed. I did try casting both to char, but that didn't help.

Comment: After reviewing it, I feel my answer is of low quality, so I will remove it to encourage additional answers.

Comment: Just throwing it out there.. did you check the Data Flow Path Editor before the look up and confirm that EmployerPAYReference column is of type DT_STR?

Comment: Godzilla, it shows as DT_I4. Can/should I do something to change it?

Comment: your final output datatype from query is varchar. please check how it shows up on SSIS. Compare it with the datatype of the lookup column in the lookup editor. May be this can help http://clip2net.com/s/igoBNR

Answer (score 0):

DT_I4 is a 4-byte integer; I'm not sure how SSIS managed to turn

```
CAST(CAST(TaxDistrictNumber AS int) AS varchar(3)) + '/' + whatever
```

into an integer, but maybe someone more knowledgeable can answer that question!

Anyway, you need to add a Data Conversion between the Source and the Lookup, and convert the column to DT_STR. In my case, because I want the output column name to be EmployerPAYEReference, I changed the original CAST in the Source to name the column INP_EmployerPAYEReference, and then set the converted column name to EmployerPAYEReference.

Answer (score 0):

A frequent source of this error is that all strings are converted to unicode strings by default by SSIS.
You can fix this by altering the columns of your main flow using the Advanced Editor 
OR 
Convert them to NCHAR\NVARCHAR in your Lookup query.